# R Map CSV & SHP

Tags: r, csv, gis, shapefile

I'm trying to plot latitude & longitude coordinates on top of a shapefile.  I am told they have the same coordinate system (NAD27).  I have tried numerous ways after researching it, but nothing works perfectly.  They either map one or the other, but not both.  Below is an example of reading them in, but I don't even know how to begin starting to plot since my csv is from the sp package my the shp is from the maptools package.

```
pts <- read.csv("locations.csv")
pts <- pts[,4:5]
names(pts) <- c("Latitude", "Longitude")
pts <- pts[complete.cases(pts),]
pts <- SpatialPoints(pts)
border <- maptools::readShapePoly("landman_one shape.shp")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below are the different structures.

```
> str(pts)
Formal class 'SpatialPoints' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  ..@ coords     : num [1:372, 1:2] 30.9 30.9 31 31 31 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:372] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Latitude" "Longitude"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 29.5 -105.2 36 -76.1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Latitude" "Longitude"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA

> str(border)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Id       : int 0
  .. ..$ PERIM_GEO: num 998432
  .. ..- attr(*, "data_types")= chr [1:2] "N" "F"
  ..@ polygons   :List of 1
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 922511 545445
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 3.45e+10
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:252, 1:2] 954182 954073 954006 953914 953828 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 922511 545445
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 3.45e+10
  ..@ plotOrder  : int 1
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 819851 386743 1042230 669865
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA
```

Also, I'm not too familiar with projections, so any guidance with that would be appreciated.  Also, if there's a way to do this with the same package I'd be open to that.

Comment: would you post links to your datasets, or perhaps use one from a web link or specific package?

Comment: It sounds like they have different projections, probably because `maptools::readShapePoly()` doesn't load a projection by default and so must be specified. Check with `str(pts)` and `str(border)` and post the results

Comment: Nate, I'll try to put something together, but most of my data is classified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that neither of your spatial data sets have a projection set and are using different coordinate systems. You can see this in the `@proj4string` line, which are both currently `NA`. A quick way to ascertain that the coordinate systems are different is with the `@bbox` slot ('bounding box'). In `pts` these are longitude/latitude as they are within -180/+180 and -90/+90 respectively. `border`, on the other hand, has values that are in entirely different units (`819851 386743 1042230 669865`). Neither of these look to be in the `NAD27` coordinate system.

To solve this, first I would use `rgdal::readOGR()` or `sf::read_sf()` to read in your `border` shape file. These functions load in a projection if one is present, so this should tell you what projection this data is in.

Second, to set the projection for `pts` you can use `proj4string()`:

```
proj4string(pts) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

Once both `pts` and `border` have a projection set, you can transform one to the other coordinate system with `spTransform()`. As I don't know what the CRS/projection for `border` is I'll convert this to WGS84 (the projection of `pts`), but just swap them to convert `pts` to the same projection as `border` once you know its CRS.

```
border = spTransform(border, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

Once in the same projection they should plot together. You can confirm their projections match with:

```
proj4string(border) == proj4string(pts)
```

Comment: I've been able to get them onto to the same system, but which plotting script would work? I'm trying to research how to plot them with sp.

Comment: @pvic Sorry, what do you mean by plotting script? If you mean how should you plot then there are plenty of tutorials accessible with a quick Google search. tmap has a nice syntax.

Comment: I wad to reload some libraries that were causing my plotting to not work.  I ended up ussing the  sp::plot with the add = TRUE attribute.  thanks for the help phil.